# How to get value from clicked radio button by refer its class name using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 radio buttons with same class what I need is when i click on particular radio button ,then value of that radio button should get in alert  by referring class name of radio button below script is not working for my requirement.

```js
if($("input[type='radio'].radioBtn").prop('checked')) {
    var btntype = $("input[type='radio'].radioBtn:checked").val();
    alert(btntype);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="numbers" value="1" />1<br/>
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="numbers" value="2" />2<br/>
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="numbers" value="3" />3<br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `click` event to fire your function each time someone clicked a input value. You can read more about events in the [jQuery API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputs").on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
    alert($(this).val()); // this points to the clicked element
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="inputs">
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="numbers" value="1" />1<br/>
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="numbers" value="2" />2<br/>
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="numbers" value="3" />3<br/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: initially <div id="inputs">  will be display:none  so if I perform any action like button click then only it will visible but immediately showing empty alert because previouly it was hidden  so if i click on button it is showing empty alert

Comment: Why it isn't visible?

Answer (score 0):

Code listen all changes in body with elements "input[type='radio'].radioBtn". When you click on radio button there are a event which target value is what you need. It`s a value of current radio button
Try this code:

```js
$("body").on("change", "input[type='radio'].radioBtn", function (event) {
    alert(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="numbers" value="1" />1<br/>
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="numbers" value="2" />2<br/>
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="numbers" value="3" />3<br/>

</body>
</html>
```